# UWP xaml property set at UserControl level not taking effect

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, winui

I have following xaml

```
<GridView 
    x:Name="gird_view" 
    Grid.Column="1" 
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind workers}"
    ContainerContentChanging="gird_view_ContainerContentChanging">
    <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10"/>
        </Style>
    </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Worker">
            <local:WorkerControl ViewModel="{x:Bind}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

In another xaml file:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="XBind.View.WorkerControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:XBind.View"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400"
    Background="BlueViolet">

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="100" BorderBrush="SkyBlue" BorderThickness="1">
        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.MyName_First,Mode=OneWay}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.MyAge_Years,Mode=OneWay}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.MyWork_Years,Mode=OneWay}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Code behind file:

```
public sealed partial class WorkerControl : UserControl, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public WorkerControl()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    ...
}
```

Background color of each `GridViewItem` is not coming up as "BlueViolet". If I set the background on `StackPanel`, it takes effect. Why does it not work when I set it on UserControl?
Reason why I am trying this is so that I can set `IsEnabled` property on `UserControl` which is not available on `StackPanel`. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [UWP UserControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.usercontrol?view=winrt-22621#remarks) documentation, you need to define the background color of the root element.

> Note that UserControl does not manifest the value of its property in
> its control template. Instead, **set the Background of the root element
> inside the UserControl**. For more info, see Remarks in
> [Control.Background](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.control.background?view=winrt-22621#remarks).

Comment: Is it only `Control.Background` that cannot be set at `UserControl` level? Even when I set `IsEnabled="False"` at `UserControl` it is not taking effect.

Comment: UserControl does not manifest the value of its property in its control template. It is recommended that you manipulate the root element of UserControl.